I am trying to add two appbar components on top of each other using Material Ui, how do i get rid of the line that appears separating the two appbars
I'm trying to add two AppBar components in Material-UI, one on top of the other. However, I'm encountering an issue where a line appears at the end of the first AppBar, on top of the second.
Here's a picture that illustrates the issue: image
I tried to remove this line by setting margins and padding to 0 or -1, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on the output. I also tried setting aria-hidden to true, but that didn't work either.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

  <AppBar
      position="sticky"
      elevation={0}
      className="bg-secondary rounded-2xl pl-4 pr-3 py-3"
    >

Try to add elevation={0},
when I duplicate same AppBar in a flex column it hides that shadow
